# Create new RDP application on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, rdp

This might be a stupid / simple question, but I need to create a new RDP application link in Windows server 2016, and I just can't remember how to do it.

To clarify, I need a link (ending in .rdp) that when you click it, opens an application located on another RDP desktop, not just the whole desktop itself (for example, opens Quickbooks on another server in the same domain).  I know there's a way to do it because the previous sysadmin in for my environment did it, and I even knew how to do this a few months ago but did it so rarely I forgot, and Google searches have been completely useless in finding this out.  Anyone Windows admins know the answer?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.kimknight.net/remoteapptool

Comment: That works, thanks!  But I swear there was something build into server 2016 that does this already...

Answer (score 2):

There are articles that describe the steps to do this, but it's easier to use the remoteapp tool:

http://kimknight.net/remoteapptool

More information:

http://techgenix.com/host-remoteapps-windows-pcs-part1/

http://techgenix.com/host-remoteapps-windows-pcs-part2/

Edit Registry to Configure RemoteApps

You can edit the Registry to turn on and configure RemoteApp support.

To enable RemoteApp support you must modify the fDisabledAllowList value:

Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\TSAppAllowList
Value: fDisabledAllowList
Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1 Enable, 0 Disable

Then you need to create a new key named Applications:

Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\TSAppAllowList\Applications

Next you need to create a new key inside Applications for each application you want to host as a RemoteApp named to describe the RemoteApp:

Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\TSAppAllowList\Applications
Subkey Name: (short name for the application you want to host as a RemoteApp)

Then you must at least create a string value named Path for each application to point to the application you want to host as a RemoteApp:

Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\TSAppAllowList\Applications\application_name
Name: Path
Type: REG_SZ

Then for each application you can optionally add additional string values (REG_SZ):

```
IconPath  
Name  
RequiredCommandLine  
SecurityDescriptor  
VPath
```

And optional DWORD values for each application:

```
CommandLineSetting  
IconIndex  
ShownInTSWA
```

Next, create an .RDP file using a text editor to launch your RemoteApp:

```
full address:s:SERVER_ADDRESS
alternate full address:s:SERVER_ADDRESS
remoteapplicationprogram:s:||REMOTEAPP_NAME
remoteapplicationname:s: REMOTEAPP_NAME
remoteapplicationcmdline:s:
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:1
redirectsmartcards:i:1
devicestoredirect:s:*
drivestoredirect:s:*
redirectdrives:i:1
session bpp:i:32
prompt for credentials on client:i:1
span monitors:i:1
use multimon:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:1
server port:i:3389
allow font smoothing:i:1
promptcredentialonce:i:0
authentication level:i:2
disableremoteappcapscheck:i:1
alternate shell:s:rdpinit.exe
screen mode id:i:2
winposstr:s:0,3,0,0,800,600
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:2
disable wallpaper:i:1
allow desktop composition:i:1
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
audiomode:i:0
redirectdirectx:i:1
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:
remoteapplicationicon:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called a RemoteApp. You have to setup a Remote Desktop Services farm, and then publish your RemoteApps on a collection :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/welcome-to-rds